# Error installing command line appium on macos

Tags: macos, command-line

on running command npm install -g appium

Following error is shown:

/usr/local/bin/authorize-ios -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/.bin/authorize-ios
/usr/local/bin/appium -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js

> appium-chromedriver@4.11.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver
>   node install-npm.js

(node:2007) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/201935-2007-2pczhq.vag1r'
(node:2007) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2007) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[15:57:21] [Chromedriver Install] Installing Chromedriver version '2.46' for platform 'mac' and architecture '64'
[15:57:21] [Chromedriver Install] Opening temp file to write 'chromedriver_mac64' to...
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/201935-2007-12eqg3q.3n01'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@4.11.0 install: `node install-npm.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appium-chromedriver@4.11.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-05T10_27_23_058Z-debug.log
sh-3.2#

We tried giving sudo access to logged in user still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems appium-chromedriver has got issue if you are behind a proxy. You may install Appium Desktop as per the discussion [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/12369) .

Never try 'sudo' with Appium.